# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in OSX WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, automatic-ref-counting

I'm building a simple application with a web view to wrap an HTML5 app for OSX. The web view listens for messages from the app, then calls some javascript functions to send some data back. This works perfectly until I try to load another page onto the web view. It looks like in the background the web view releases the ResourceLoadDelegate then tries to call it again, resulting in my error message.

My project uses one class as a giant app delegate, and I've the UIDelegate, ResourceLoadDelegate, and FrameLoadDelegate all set to "self". I don't get the error if I don't have the ResourceLoadDelegate set, but then I can't receive messages.

Does anyone know what my problem could be? Here is my code:

**My header:**

```
@interface BFAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    WebView *webView;
} 

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet WebView *webView;

@end
```

**My class:**

```
@implementation BFAppDelegate
@synthesize webView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.webView setUIDelegate:self];
    [self.webView setResourceLoadDelegate:self];
    [self.webView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
}

-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:message]];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have linked **WebKit.framework** in the General Settings of your Target.

1. In the Project Browser click on the Project (first item)
2. Go to the "General"-Tab
3. Under **"Linked Frameworks and Libraries"** click the plus icon.
4. Search for *WebKit.framework*
5. Select it and hit "Add".
6. Boom! We're done!

*Also don't forget to import* **WebKit/WebKit.h** in your header file(s).

[image: Linked Frameworks and Libraries]

I hope I can help you with that.